# Setting 32-bit x86 build target in Visual C# 2008 Express Edition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, com, 32-bit

I'm building a C# application that loads a 32-bit COM dll. The compiled application runs fine on 32-bit Windows but barfs on 64 bit Windows because it can't load the 32-bit COM. Is there a way to set a 32-bit build target in VC# 2008 Express Edition?

Alternatively, is there a way to force a .NET application compiled to the *AnyCPU* build target to run in 32-bit mode on 64-bit Windows?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot explicitly set it to 32-bit in the UI in VS Express, but apparently (I only have the Professional version at hand) it can be done using a bit of setting up. [This](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/4377.aspx#22601) forum post has details on how to do it.

What you can also do is to use the [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699.aspx) tool that comes with the [.Net Framework SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fe6f2099-b7b4-4f47-a244-c96d69c35dec&displaylang=en) to set the compiled output to run as 32-bit. To set the 32-bit flag using CorFlags, run this from the command line:

```
CorFlags.exe /32BIT+ yourapp.exe
```

This will set a flag in the header of your exe to signal to .Net that it should be run as 32-bit.

Comment: Thanks so much. The directions on the linked page worked great. -- allowed me to select 32 bit from the GUI

Answer (score 26):

For posterity, here is the forum post adrian linked to:

> In VC# Express, this property is
>   missing, but you can still create an
>   x86 configuration if you know where to
>   look.
>
> It looks like a long list of steps,
>   but once you know where these things
>   are it's a lot easier. Anyone who only
>   has VC# Express will probably find
>   this useful. Once you know about
>   Configuration Manager, it'll be much
>   more intuitive the next time.
>
> 1. In VC# Express 2005, go to Tools -> Options.
> 2. In the bottom-left corner of the Options dialog, check the box that
>      says, "Show all settings".
> 3. In the tree-view on the left hand side, select "Projects and Solutions".
> 4. In the options on the right, check the box that says, "Show advanced
>      build configuraions."
> 5. Click OK.
> 6. Go to Build -> Configuration Manager...
> 7. In the Platform column next to your project, click the combobox and select
>      "".
> 8. In the "New platform" setting, choose "x86".
> 9. Click OK.
> 10. Click Close.
>
> There, now you have an x86
>   configuration! Easy as pie! :-)
>
> I also recommend using Configuration
>   Manager to delete the Any CPU
>   platform. You really don't want that
>   if you ever have depedencies on 32-bit
>   native DLLs (even indirect
>   dependencies).

Comment: Note that in Visual Studio 2010, you need to click "Tools > Settings > Expert Settings" before the "Build" menu will show up. Also, I don't think that steps #1~5 are necessary in 2010.