# signed/verified .exe gives unknown publisher

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-signing

Visual Basic Express 2008, developed vb.net database app. on Win7 x64 PC.

I changed build config. manager to platform: x86, so the .exe runs on both x86 and x64 machines. Last answer here: [Setting 32-bit x86 build target in Visual C# 2008 Express Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381968/setting-32-bit-x86-build-target-in-visual-c-sharp-2008-express-edition)

Purchased MS Authenticode cert. from Symantec/Verisign, received cert, installed in browser. Exported cert. from browser to .pfx. In VS properties/signing tab, checked sign teh assembly then navigated to the .pfx.

after a build, used signtool to sign the .exe

```
signtool.exe sign /ac "c:\users\me\desktop\debugv6\winCert.cer" /s MY /t  http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll /n "Our Company Inc." /v c:\users\me\desktop\debugv6\db.exe

The following certificate was selected:
Issued to: Our Company Inc.
Issued by: VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2010 CA
Expires:   7/31/2014 6:59:59 PM
SHA1 hash: xxlongStringxx

Done Adding Additional Store

Attempting to sign: c:\users\me\desktop\debugv6\db.exe
Successfully signed and timestamped: c:\users\me\desktop\debugv6\db.exe

Number of files successfully Signed: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0
```

then used signtool to verify

```
signtool.exe verify /pa /v c:\users\me\desktop\debugv6\db.exe

Verifying: c:\users\me\desktop\debugv6\db.exe
SHA1 hash of file: xxlongStringxx
Signing Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
    Issued by: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
    Expires:   7/16/2036 6:59:59 PM
    SHA1 hash: xxlongStringxx

        Issued to: VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2010 CA
        Issued by: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
        Expires:   2/7/2020 6:59:59 PM
        SHA1 hash: xxlongStringxx

            Issued to: Our Company Inc.
            Issued by: VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2010 CA
            Expires:   7/31/2014 6:59:59 PM
            SHA1 hash: xxlongStringxx

The signature is timestamped: 7/31/2013 4:18:46 PM
Timestamp Verified by:
    Issued to: Thawte Timestamping CA
    Issued by: Thawte Timestamping CA
    Expires:   12/31/2020 6:59:59 PM
    SHA1 hash: xxlongStringxx

        Issued to: Symantec Time Stamping Services CA - G2
        Issued by: Thawte Timestamping CA
        Expires:   12/30/2020 6:59:59 PM
        SHA1 hash: xxlongStringxx

            Issued to: Symantec Time Stamping Services Signer - G4
            Issued by: Symantec Time Stamping Services CA - G2
            Expires:   12/29/2020 6:59:59 PM
            SHA1 hash: xxlongStringxx

Successfully verified: c:\users\me\desktop\debugv6\db.exe

Number of files successfully Verified: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0
```

**problem**

When launching the .exe from WinXP 32-bit systems I get Publisher: Our Company Inc. Great.
But when launching from **some** Win7 x64 machines, I get publisher: Unknown.

Anyone have this prob. before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer
VeriSign has two† paths for their current code-signing certificates. One uses the G5 as root. The other one (more compatible) uses G5 as intermediate. The solution is not only to add the secondary intermediate (as you did already) but the primary intermediate as well: [Download](http://www.verisign.com/support/verisign-intermediate-ca/code-signing-intermediate/).

Long answer

Check the certificate store on the problematic machine(s) whether you find your root (VeriSign G5), for example with Start » Execute » mmc.exe » Menu File » Add Snap-in » Certificates (Computer, Local) » Add » Trusted Third Party Certificates. If not present, I am aware of these five alternative solutions:

Alternative A (on problematic machine)

1. download ‘VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5’ (root)
2. in Windows, double-click on it and
3. at the bottom of its properties, click on ‘install certificate’

Alternative B (on problematic machine)

1. download the latest ‘Update for Root Certificates’ (KB931125) which
2. requires you to pass the Genuine Windows Validation
   (which installs several new roots, including ‘VeriSign Class 3 Public PCA – G5’)

Alternative C (on problematic machine; only Windows XP)

1. open the Windows Update-Website and
2. do not choose Express but select Custom
3. install all optional updates (which installs the ‘Update for Root Certificates’)

The user might have turned off automatic root certificate updates. In Windows XP, this can be controlled via Start » Control Panel » Software » Windows Components » Update Root Certificates. Or (in Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7) via mmc.exe » Menu File » Add Snap-in » Group Policy Object (Local) » Add » Local Computer Policy » Administrative Templates (optionally: Menu » Action » Add Templates » Add » system » Open » Close ») System » Internet » Internet » Turn off Automatic Root Certificate Update.

Alternative D

  as intermediate certificate, use an
  *older*
  ‘VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2010 CA’
  Expires: Wed Jan 01 19:59:59 2014
  SHA1 hash: 14FCF0BB187D563B568EEA5FC888A53D288698D6
  (this intermediate links to ‘Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority’ directly without G5)

Alternative E

  see the short answer. VeriSign does the same with SSL/TLS. Therefore for more details, have a look at
  [this explanation …](http://www.confusedamused.com/notebook/fixing-verisign-certificates-on-windows-servers/)

† Actually there are three paths: G5 CA as root, G5 CA as intermediate, and the old 2010 CA. G5 CA as root is the problematic path.

Examples (signed according alternative E) are Adobe Reader (currently v11.0.0.5) and Apple AirPort Utility (currently v5.6.1). By the way, there a similar guides for [browser plug-ins](https://ivan-site.com/2010/11/signing-an-xpi-using-a-verisign-code-signing-certificate/) and [kernel code drivers](http://www.64k-tec.de/2011/02/kernel-driver-code-signing-with-the-verisign-class-3-primary-ca-g5-certificate/).