# Write To Database From URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to write to a .accdb file.  When I test and do such from localhost it works w/o any issues.  However if I try to write to it from my URL it errors.  The .accdb is stored in a folder created from within VS called Database.

How should I set up/store the .accdb so I can write to it from the web?

Error message is 
The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Connetion String is
"Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Testing.accdb"

**EDIT**
if I change the connection string to 12.0 same error message

The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
**In Resposne To Comment**

 I am using VS2010 and do not have the option of in my options

> In the bottom-left corner of the Options dialog, check the box that says, "Show all settings"

This is what I see under options[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gIOo.png)

Comment: [Target 32-bit cpu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)s or use a newer ODBC driver

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - for platform the only option I have is Any CPU - I am unable to break it ouw by 32 or 64.  This is VS200

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1402666/712649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your server operating system version?You may need to install Access software on your server.

And if your Access is x86,you need to specify the x86 mode to compile your project,instead of using anycpu mode.

You'd better use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0,when your database is .accdb.

If not OK, you can try to download and install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable: url(http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) .

Comment: Server OS Version is Windows 7 64 bit.  Server has both Excel 2007 & Excel 2000 installed.

Comment: sorry,I made a mistake,not excel,it's access.  :)